# Extra Space In Results? Python Programming

Tags: python

In my program I have an extra space in between the asterisk and apostrophe in test 1 and test 2 extra space within the plus and apostrophe.  Don't need that extra space and here's my code...help haha!

Test 1:

Expected :'3 4*'

Actual   :'3 4* '

Test 2:

Expected :'3 4* -5+'

Actual   :'3 4* -5+ '

```
    def empty_case(self, mt_node, inp):

    if (inp is None):
        return ''
    else:
        return inp

def non_empty_case(self, data_node, inp):

    if (inp is None):
        inp = ""

    if (data_node.is_leaf()):
        return inp + (str(data_node.get_data()) + " ")

    inp = data_node.get_left().execute(self, inp)
    inp = data_node.get_right().execute(self, inp)

    return (inp[:-1] + str(data_node.get_data()) + " ")
```

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't seem to be related to the question you're asking.

Comment: Totally was, I apologize i just edited to the right code. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to end on a call to

```
empty_case
```

where

```
inp is None
```

So, the whitespace ' ' is appended to the end of a string you grew by parsing a tree.

I have not seen enough of your code to tell you how to fix that.
You might want to end on a non_empty_case where inp is None, instead.